# Two-dimensional array is only showing numbers instead of my string answers

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhIpm.jpg)

> the prompt show : |0 0||0 1||0 2||0 3||1 0||1 1||1 2||1 3||2 0||2 1||2 2||2 3||3 0||3 1||3 2||3 3|
>   **Wanting** the `prompt` to show out of the selected `array`

```
  /*Input the two ints to find a class, Time and Date.*/   
  import java.util.*; 


 public class Time
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String [][] schedule = new String [4] [4]; //2D Array variables below
        // ***Course, Date and Times***

        schedule[0] [0] = "C149, Mon 2:00";
        schedule[0] [1] = "C149, Tue 3:00";
        schedule[0] [2] = "C149, Wed 4:00";
        schedule[0] [3] = "C149, Thu 5:00";
        schedule[1] [0] = "C150 Mon 2:00";
        schedule[1] [1] = "C150, Tue 3:00";
        schedule[1] [2] = "C150, Wed 4:00";
        schedule[1] [3] = "C150, Thu 5:00";
        schedule[2] [0] = "M920 Mon 2:00";
        schedule[2] [1] = "M920, Tue 3:00";
        schedule[2] [2] = "M920, Wed 4:00";
        schedule[2] [3] = "M920, Thu 5:00";
        schedule[3] [0] = "P150 Mon 2:00";
        schedule[3] [1] = "P150, Tue 3:00";
        schedule[3] [2] = "P150, Wed 4:00";
        schedule[3] [3] = "P150, Thu 5:00";


       // ***'row'*** 
       // ***'column'***   


       System.out.println(" Courses:    (0)CIT149, (1) CIT150,   (2)MAT920,   (3)PIE150"); //My Rows
    System.out.println(" Date&Time: (0)Mon 2:00 (1)Tue 3:00, (2)Wed 4:00, (3)Thu 5:00,"); //My Columns

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a Course:");
    int row = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a Day and Time:");
    int column = input.nextInt();

    // My **Loops**

    if(row < schedule.length && column < schedule[row].length) 
    {



        for(int r = 0; r < schedule.length + 1 ; ++r)
        {
            row = r;
            int c;

            for(c = 0; c < schedule[r].length; ++c);
            {
                    column = c;


            System.out.print(schedule[r][c]); // I think this is my problem

            }
        }

    }   
    else
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, please take the tour and read the help center.

Comment: Please visit [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question...a lot.

Comment: How are you encountering this? I can't replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

change your both loops from this

```
for(int r = 0; r < schedule.length + 1 ; ++r)
    {
        row = r;
        int c;

        for(c = 0; c < schedule[r].length; ++c); //remove this semi colon
        {
                column = c;


        System.out.print(schedule[r][c]); 

        }
    }
```

to this

```
for (int r = 0; r < schedule.length; r++) {
            if (row == r) {
                for (int c = 0; c < schedule[r].length; c++) {
                    if (column == c) {
                        System.out.print(schedule[r][c]); 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
```